# Apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Tags: android, firebase

The moment I add this line to the bottom of build.gradle as it is requested in the Firebase guide Android Studio gives an error:

```
Cause: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.isEmpty(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:246)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDomainObjectSet$DomainObjectCompositeCollection.isEmpty(CompositeDomainObjectSet.java:172)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.isEmpty(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:246)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DelegatingDomainObjectSet.isEmpty(DelegatingDomainObjectSet.java:102)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DelegatingDomainObjectSet.isEmpty(DelegatingDomainObjectSet.java:102)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDomainObjectSet$DomainObjectCompositeCollection.isEmpty(CompositeDomainObjectSet.java:172)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDomainObjectSet.iterator(CompositeDomainObjectSet.java:111)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DelegatingDomainObjectSet.iterator(DelegatingDomainObjectSet.java:106)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDomainObjectSet$DomainObjectCompositeCollection.iterator(CompositeDomainObjectSet.java:201)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.SetIterator.of(SetIterator.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDomainObjectSet.iterator(CompositeDomainObjectSet.java:114)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DelegatingDomainObjectSet.iterator(DelegatingDomainObjectSet.java:106)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDomainObjectSet$DomainObjectCompositeCollection.iterator(CompositeDomainObjectSet.java:201)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.SetIterator.of(SetIterator.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDomainObjectSet.iterator(CompositeDomainObjectSet.java:114)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DelegatingDomainObjectSet.iterator(DelegatingDomainObjectSet.java:106)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDomainObjectSet$DomainObjectCompositeCollection.iterator(CompositeDomainObjectSet.java:201)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.SetIterator.of(SetIterator.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDomainObjectSet.iterator(CompositeDomainObjectSet.java:114)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DelegatingDomainObjectSet.iterator(DelegatingDomainObjectSet.java:106)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the classpath to the Gradle, root build.gradle.

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```